# Как выровнять надписи по центру в каждом из блоков независимо от высоты?

Tags: html, css, css3, bootstrap, выравнивание

Есть контейнер с блоками на `bootstrap`. Как сделать универсальный (не зависеть от количества текста и высоты блока) адаптивный вариант выровненных надписей в блоках по горизонтальному и вертикальному центру с кроссбраузерностью `ie9+`?
[Фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26938/) Практически получилось сделать, единственное, если нужна определенная высота для основного блока, то так не работает. Как довести до универсального варианта?

```css
.main {
background-color: #231f20;
color:#fff;
    min-height: 100px;
height:1px;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
background-color: red;
}
.table {
display:table;
table-layout: fixed;
width:100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: blue;
margin-bottom:0;
}
.table-cell {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align: center;
  float: none !important;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="table">
<div class="col-sm-3 table-cell">
  <p>test</p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 table-cell">
  <p>test<br />test</p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 table-cell">
  <p>test<br />test<br />test</p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 table-cell">
  <p>test<br />test</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Делай на флексах. align-items, align-content

Comment: @Дмитрий Приходченко кроссбраузерность `ie9+` - читайте внимательно описание. `flex` - не универсальный вариант..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
section {
  height: 200px;
  background: silver;
  text-align: center;
}

section:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<section><div>
    <p>test</p>
  </div><div>
    <p>test<br />test</p>
  </div><div>
    <p>test<br />test<br />test</p>
  </div><div>
    <p>test<br />test</p>
  </div><div>
    <p>test</p>
</div></section>
```

Форматирование такое [не случайно](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468550/178988). Ещё стоит заметить, что между `<section><div>` тоже не должно быть пробелов, иначе он появятся из-за `:before` между ним и первым блоком (ещё и центрирование этим нарушится).

Comment: красиво, то в таком случае теряется бутстраповская резиновость, т.е.под каждое разрешение придется задавать свои отступы ?

Comment: @Вася, не думаю, но вообще-то не очень понял вопрос. Можно уточнить, какую именно резиновость требуется получить? А вообще, можно применить flex.

Comment: потестировал - нет, все хорошо, не теряется. `flex` можно, но не под эту задачу, т.к. нужна кроссбраузерность `ie9+`

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вам просто нужно добавить **text-align** в блок .table-cell.

Вот так:

```css
.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: нет, не правильно поняли - вы видите, что строки не выровнены по вертикальному центру? в этом самая сложность

Answer (score 0):

Надо было еще просто добавить в стили `.row {height:100%;}`. [Вот](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26938/) универсальный и кроссбраузерный `ie9+` вариант

```css
.main {
  background-color: #231f20;
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 100px;
  height: 1px;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
.row {
  height: 100%;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  float: none !important;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="table">
        <div class="col-sm-3 table-cell">
          <p>test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 table-cell">
          <p>test
            <br />test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 table-cell">
          <p>test
            <br />test
            <br />test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 table-cell">
          <p>test
            <br />test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```